# CSS selector image not displaying in website banner or in Chrome's Developer Tools window

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website with a large banner that displays differently on each page. The background image is not displaying when I put the background image on the page selector but it will work on the main banner CSS code.

This is for my wordpress site (WordPress 5.2) running a completely custom theme developed from scratch by me. Running PHP version: 7.0.33.

.page-id-15 .bannerImage {}
.postid-15 .bannerImage {}

I have tried both background image and background color with Chrome Developer Tools not displaying that it is seeing this style.

I have confirmed the correct page/post id of 15.

I have put the background image/color into .bannerImage and it displays as expected.

Not sure what else to try. This should be easy.

/// This will display background image and/or color ///

```
.bannerImage {
    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 337px;

    /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

/// This will not display background image and/or color (showing color style)  ///

```
.page-id-15 .bannerImage { background-color: #35CC4B; }
.postid-15 .bannerImage { background-color: #35CC4B; }
```

/// HTML Code ///

```
<div class="bannerImage">
   <h2>Contact Us</h2>
</div>
```

/// Word Press Admin URL to show correct page/post number ///

```
http://box5308.temp.domains/~naiedmon/wp-admin/post.php?post=15&action=edit
```

/// URL ///

```
http://box5308.temp.domains/~naiedmon/contact-us
```

I expect to see a banner that is 337px high with a width of 100% that is different on each page.
What I actually see is a blank white banner space with the H2 displaying.
Chrome only outputs the .bannerImage selector and not the .page-id-15 .bannerImage or .postid-15 .bannerImage selector.

---

***** updated *****

Below I have added the code I am seeing when I look at Chrome Developer Tools. Unlike the suggestions I completely agree with should work (I have tried), my selector tag of .page-id-15 .bannerImage {} is not be read by the browser and displayed. I did also attempt .postid-15 .bannerImage {}. This is where it has me stumped.

[Screen Capture of Code from Chrome Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmL8.png)

Comment: What if you do `background-image: url("imgURLhere.gif") !important;` ?? Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well. I apologize as I forgot I did try this (always a first thing I try) as I have been researching this for 2 days (ugh). It should be a simple thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwriting forced wordpress CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703536/overwriting-forced-wordpress-css-styles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I was able to get help in the WordPress.org forum and so I thought I would put the answer here in case someone else has this problem.*

**What I did:**

So, for some reason I decided to write my body tag like this (and continued to overlook the error):

`<body class="body" <?php body_class(); ?> >`.

I do not need to call the class "body". Once I deleted `class="body"` the correct body string was written and I can now call styles by page id.

**The correct body tag in my case looks like this:**

`<body class="page-template page-template-page_fullwidth page-template-page_fullwidth-php page page-id-394 page-parent logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support" >`

**The exact advice I received:**

> The main problem is that you’re not calling the body_class() function
>   in your theme. Once you do that, the right body classes (like
>   page-id-15, etc) will be associated with the body element. Right now,
>   your body element looks like: `<body class="topgradient">`
>
> If you change your site to another WordPress theme, and then inspect
>   the body element, you’ll see what it’s supposed to look like.

I am very thankful for communities like this and others!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress sometimes re-writes your CSS. I had this problem before. try using "!important" in all of your CSS attributes. this probably works.

Comment: I have tried using "!important" but have had no luck. Where I get stuck is that I would think that it should at least show in the Chrome Developer Tools and be crossed out but nothing is showing there when I use the page selector of "page-id-##".

Answer (score 0):

I have had to move on and find another solution to my problem. Unfortunately I have not been able to successfully work with page ids as CSS selectors. My solution around the problem was to add additional classes and call them that way.

Example being on my about page to make a selector .about and attach my background image to that class. A simple fix but I was hoping to understand why I couldn't get the page id to work as a selector.

Onward and upward! Thank you to the community for your responses and attempts to help me out on this!